# Opening local *.accdb file through ArcGIS API for Flex button?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer, accdb

I have a web mapping application created with the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex application builder.

Is there a way to create a button that will open a local accdb file?

I dont want to connect to MS Access through my app. I just want to open the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex applications run in the flash sandbox. They do not have access to files on the client directly. Hence it is not possible to open a file as such.

Comment: Sorry this is my first app and i'm new to this..There is no way they can see data from ms access even if i use data access pages or convert my file into a web ms access? (The app is designed for our intranet)

Comment: Generally, there is a web service which talks to a database backend. The Flex app can communicate with the webservice, and get the data etc. So your option is to make a web service on your server.

Comment: thank you for pointing in the right direction. I will try to find the way to do it.

Comment: Depending on how often the access database is updated - another option, instead of connecting to a database backend and creating the web service, might be to export the access file to something that the Flex API can read directly (from your web server).  For example, for point data, a CSV file.